# Mysql & PHP won't echo the results of the query

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "usbw");
mysql_select_db("europese unie");

$id = $_GET['Land'];
$query = "SELECT `Land`, `Oppervlakte`, `Inwoners`, `Klimaat`, `Motto`, `UTC` FROM `algemene informatie` WHERE `Land` = '$id'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$land = $row[0];

echo "$land"; 



print("<h2>$id</h2>");
print("<br />");


die(mysql_error())

?>
```

when i tried to run this code i expected to echo the first land that came up with this query instead i got nothing. i am not a very experienced PHP or Mysql user nor is english my first language so pleas do not hold annything against me.

Comment: Whats the output of `var_dump($row)`?

Comment: have you tried echo $land;

Comment: This is a dangerous query using a $_GET variable directly in a query.  Read up on SQL injections and look into using PDO with prepared statements.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: Sidenote: Slap a semi-colon at the end of `die(mysql_error())`

Comment: First try to get anything from database with query : `SELECT `Land`, `Oppervlakte`, `Inwoners`, `Klimaat`, `Motto`, `UTC` FROM `algemene informatie` WHERE 1` . Maybe you don't have a row with THIS particular `$id` . Besides I dont know if you can name your table with space, this might be an error also. And third of all, you should call fields like this: ``algemene informatie`.`Land``

Comment: var_dump($row) gives bool(false)

Comment: Spaces in a database could cause some unexpected results `mysql_select_db("europese unie");`

Comment: `$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
print_r($row);`

Comment: @SebastianPiskorski after i used that query i got the first row of the table. and i know there should be a row with that $id because i got the $id from the same table. also thank you for that about the space i will look into it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- made it into europese-unie

Comment: @user3498790 Ah, ok. Just double-checking.

Comment: I tested your code and it worked fine. You could try removing the quotes in `'$id'"` to `$id"` but it may not even work any better. Make sure you have data in the given columns, with no spelling mistakes. @user3498790 Plus, remember to add a semi-colon at the end of `die(mysql_error())` should you have any other code below it. That alone will break your code, IF you have more code below that; just saying.

Comment: You could also try changing `$land = $row[0];` to `$land = $row[1];` @user3498790 if there is no data in your first column, just to test it out.

Comment: @Fred-ii- well the adress is _http://localhost:8080/details.php?Land=%20Belgie_ and `$id = $_GET['Land'];`is the id so Belgie should be $id but as `var_dump($result)` it keeps giving `bool(false)`

Comment: Use some tool like Navicat Premium or SQL console or phpmyadmin to be certain that THIS id in THIS table exists. Your query looks ok. Maybe `$_GET['Land']` is empty. Did you'd check it?

Comment: @user3498790 Does typing in `...details?Land=Belgie` without the space give you a result? That `%20` is a space btw. That could be the problem. You could make use of `trim()`

Comment: Basically what you're asking SQL, is to find `(space)Belgie` and since your column doesn't contain the word Belgie with a space, it will not find it; least that's what I think is happening @user3498790

Comment: @Fred-ii- how should i do this?

Comment: @SebastianPiskorski i'm using phpmyadmin because im doing this with usbwebserver as a assignment. i'm sorry for not providing this information earlier.

Comment: Try using `$id = trim($_GET['Land']);` @user3498790

Comment: @Fred-ii-thank you `print_r($row);` now gives Array ( [0] => Belgie [1] => 31 [2] => 11 [3] => gematigd zeeklimaat [4] => Eendracht maakt macht [5] => 1 ) i can finaly proceed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved**

Taken from comments:

*"well the adress is `localhost:8080/details.php?Land=%20Belgie` and `$id = $_GET['Land'];` is the id so Belgie should be `$id` but as `var_dump($result)` it keeps giving `bool(false)`"*

- Basically what you're asking SQL, is to find `(space)Belgie` and since your column doesn't contain the word Belgie with a space, it will not find it; least that's what I think is happening

That `%20` is a space btw. That could be the problem. You could make use of the [`trim()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function.

Use:

```
$id = trim($_GET['Land']);
```

---

OP:

> thank you print_r($row); now gives Array ( [0] => Belgie [1] => 31 [2] => 11 [3] => gematigd zeeklimaat [4] => Eendracht maakt macht [5] => 1 ) i can finaly proceed

---

Sidenote: Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/mysqli) functions. (which I recommend you use and with [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo))

`mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will be removed from future PHP releases.

---

**Footnotes:**

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `mysql_connect()` this is going to become outdated, use `mysqli_connect()`.

I.e.:

```
$connection = new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'db table', 'portnumber');

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        printf("<b>Connection failed:</b> %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit;
    }
```

run you query through mysqli object and remember to use injection prevention or you will get people hacking you site.

e.g.

http://www.phphaven.com/article.php?id=65

Hope that helps

Comment: when i do this i get this error **Class 'mysqli_connect' not found in G:\... on line 20**

Comment: That's because you're already using `mysql_*` functions. This answer doesn't qualify as an answer, per se. @user3498790 if you haven't changed all your functions for `mysqli` API, then don't use this.

Comment: If you are using a local LAMP stack then you need to install this hopefully you can just enable this in your php.ini i.e. ;extension=mysqli.so change to extension=mysqli.so

Comment: Fred's comment is valid although if you enable strict PHP programming you will get a tone of warnings, learn PHP right and use recommended up to date functions and objects!!!

Answer (score 0):

Quote out the variables.

```
echo $land;

print("<h2>" . $id . "</h2>");
```